# Scaling animation using a surfaceview and canvas

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, android-canvas, scaling

I'm attempting to build my first game but I'm having an issue determining the correct way to implement a scaling animation. I want to draw a cannon on my canvas and before it fires I want it to slowly scale up to about three times it's original size. (First original size, then 1.5x, then 2.5x, 3 original size)

Should I be using the canvas to draw a new cannon bitmap using the Bitmap.scalebitmap method or a sprite-sheet or someother method? (2D graphics)

Also does anyone know of any tutorials regarding this topic?

Thank you

Comment: the easiest is to use std Animations e.g. ScaleAnimation, all you need to do is to add some dozen lines of code to support them in your drawing code

Comment: @pskink the Android animation class applies to view object such as the mathlayouts, imageview etc. I maybe missing something. Can you provide a code example of how you'd apply an animation on canvas? Thank you

Comment: sure, see this: https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable/blob/master/PatchworkDrawableLibrary/src/org/pskink/patchworkdrawable/drawable/PatchworkDrawable.java,  lines                   366..400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property animations are also a good option for scaling and its super easy! here is my code for scaling down a layout to 0 and then back it normal. you can get what you want with simple modifications.

```
    private void anim() {
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();

    ValueAnimator fadeOld = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1,(float)0);
    fadeOld.setDuration(100);
    fadeOld.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    fadeOld.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            Float newValue = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            cardContainer.setScaleX(newValue);
            cardContainer.setScaleY(newValue);
            cardContainer.setAlpha(newValue);


        }
    });

    ValueAnimator showNew = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    showNew.setDuration(150);
    showNew.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    showNew.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            Float newValue = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            cardContainer.setScaleX(newValue);
            cardContainer.setScaleY(newValue);
            cardContainer.setAlpha(newValue);
        }
    });


    set.play(fadeOld);
    set.play(showNew).after(fadeOld);
    set.start();

}
```